# Resizing images to fit width in ipython

Tags: markdown, ipython

Can anyone get images to fit width in **Firefox** using, say, custom CSS without leaving a lot of white space at the bottom of the cell? A minimal Markdown example with `custom.css` is appreciated. Here is something to replicate the problem:

Cell one:

```
![Big image](http://cantelofmedford.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/oversize1.jpg)

See the white space after this?
```

Cell two:

```
%run talktools.py
```

Now execute both cells. The image will not fit unless you create a custom css with the following entry: `p img {width: 100%;}` And when you do that, there will be white space at the bottom of the first cell:

[image: Screenshot with Firefox 26 under Ubuntu]

Comment: Do you have a code example or an image? As it stands now your question is very unclear.

Comment: @MattDMo: Just use any large image; the point of the exercise is to shrink the image to fit the width of the notebook. You can insert an image with Markdown in the notebook as follows: `![caption](file/file_name)` Which part is unclear?

Comment: @Emre, mainly that you ask for a "minimal Markdown example with `custom.css`", but you don't provide anything of the kind to us. It sounds like you're looking for free development. Showing that you have a good understanding of the problem and that you've tried to resolve it yourself goes a long way on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Guys, just create a notebook with just a Markdown cell with any old large image, inserted as explained in my last comment, and edit the `custom.css` so the image is resize, like so: `p img {width: 100%;}`

Trust me, I have tried to resolve it myself. I am plumbing in Firefox' debugger as we speak. I am not providing you with the solution because I don't have it. Otherwise what would be the point of my asking?

Comment: If there is not enough image to fill vertically when it is fitted horizontally, what do you want to happen?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean when the image is smaller than the width of the cell? If possible, resize to the width of the cell, otherwise leave them at their original size. I'm not really concerned with that case; my images are too big.

Comment: You need to consider the aspect ratio of the image. Say you have image which is 3 wide by 1 tall. There is no way to fit it into a box 3 wide by 2 tall without either leaving a gap or distorting the image (or maybe repeating it vertically). That appears to be the problem you are encountering.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Why is the box 2 tall in the first place? The cells should be no bigger than their contents. This is the case except when the image is resized to fit as I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following entries to `style.css`:

```
.cell.text_cell { display: inline-block; }
.cell p img { width: 100%; }
```

Tested on Firefox 26. A hack maybe, but it was the best I could do. If anybody finds a better solution, do share it.

Answer (score 0):

I find adding an HTML cell to update the CSS on a per-notebook basis to be a better alternative to changing style.css.

```
%%html
<style>
img { width: 100%; }
</style>
```